# d3.js Set d3-tip background to element colour

Tags: d3.js

I've created a scatter graph using the following code as a basis:

http://bl.ocks.org/peterssonjonas/4a0e7cb8d23231243e0e

However I'd like to change the background of the tooltip either based upon the colour of the selected element, or by adding a data column related to colour (i.e. d.colour).

The code currently generates tooltip text based upon the selected element via the following lines:

```
  var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr("class", "d3-tip")
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return xCat + ": " + d[xCat] + "<br>" + yCat + ": " + d[yCat];
  });
```

I was hoping that by adding something like:

```
.style("background", function(d) { return d.colour; })
```

I'd be able to achieve this. However when I do this I find that d is undefined (by adding a console.log before returning).

I'm a super novice when it comes to this kind of thing, so any advice anyone could give me would be super helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a positive criticism: don't use `d3-tip` or any other plugin to create your tooltips. Create them yourself. That way, you can have better control over them and customise them the way you want.

Back to the question: without even looking at that plugin's documentation, you can select the element (in this case, a `<div>`) by class:

```
d3.select(".d3-tip").style("background-color", color(d[colorCat]));
```

Here is the updated bl.ocks: http://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/70f2608e455b61514cc96dff6fe41ea6/65c940cb987ae1cbda5dc352cda54a382a945ae8

Regarding the `undefined`: the `tip.style` is not receiving the datum when the event is fired, apparently only `tip.html` does. To be sure about that you have to check their source code.

Comment: PS: If you create your own tooltips you can even have charts inside them, as in this dataviz I created: https://www.1point21interactive.com/lvmoviecriminals/lucky13/

Comment: Thank you so much! Couldn't have asked for a better answer, worked perfectly. The dataviz you linked is really cool, and I'll definitely take it to heart that I should be creating custom tooltips in the future. It's my first time using d3, so I was just following an example that did something close to what I wanted to do. :)